# How can I wake up a MacBook with lid closed?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, remote-control, wake-on-lan

How can I wake up my MacBook pro with an iPhone, when the lid closed (no external display)?
MacBook is not connected to power and there's a local wifi that it can connect to.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: If I wake it up, I can connect to it via TeamViewer and access files or control it.

Comment: You can't if the MacBook is also asleep, as it won't keep a WiFi connection while it's not on.

Comment: @JohnKeates well, maybe there's some trick to keep wifi connected and keep it only WOL mode or something. Maybe something could be done with Bluetooth or periphery

Comment: The wireless hardware is switched off when the computer is not on/awake, so that's the actual problem. Also, WiFi doesn't work without the OS running.

Comment: @JohnKeates but somehow when it's hooked to power and asleep (lid closed), I can wake it up remotely

Comment: To expand on that: Wake on WiFi can only be made to work if the connection is up while the computer is not in standby or off, and only on recent systems (about 4 years). Often doesn't work if there is a Bonjour sleep proxy on a different physical link (but still on the same logical network).

Comment: On power it doesn't go into standby. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202124

Comment: Can you use cabled network?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen how would that help?

Comment: It is easier to wake up remotely then

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen how do I reach it with an iPhone through cabled network then?

Comment: The iPhone can use WiFi if on the same network. The Mac can listen to wol packets on cable

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen well, mac will always to be hoocked up to lan, but WiFi can be mounted somewhere in the house. Though it's still a way around, thanks

Answer (score 1):

macOS Sierra, has an option in Energy Saver > Power Adapter to "Wake for Wi-Fi network access." In earlier versions that option was in Network preferences.

Apple Remote Access will wake a Mac this way but I am unaware of any iOS app that does this.

Generally speaking Wake On LAN (WOL) requires the sending device to send a so called "Magic Packet" and the receiving computer to be able to receive it and act upon it. I *believe* that Apple supports this method of WOL but I have not tested it in quite a while.

So your job will be to find an iOS app that provides WOL capability as it **should** do what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, but for WOL to work Mac should be connected to wifi all the time. It does when connected to power, but when its on battery, I can't find it with a network scanning app (Fing), and can't send a "waking" signal.

Comment: Then I guess you'll have to leave it connected to power for this to have any hope of working

Comment: Maybe there's some trick or Bluetooth can help or.....something